# Distribute y axis ticks evenly between minum and maximum

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am about to plot some variables (in a boxplot, but that doesn't matter) where I want to display the minimum and the maximum on the ordinate scale (y-axis).

```
require(ggplot2)

y_min <- min(PlantGrowth$weight)
y_max <- max(PlantGrowth$weight)

ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ylim(y_min, y_max)
```

Result:
[image: No minimum and maximum display]

I know, `ylim()` is not made to directly edit the y-axis labels, but when setting another range, it accidentally works:

```
ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ylim(0, 8)
```

The straightforward solution is probably defining the ticks yourself:

```
ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(seq(y_min, y_max, 1.25), y_max))
```

which almost always results in a varying distance of the last and the next-to-last tick of the y-axis. It'd requires to experiment with the by-argument of `seq()` until we a have an evenly ticked y-axis which includes the mininum and the maximum. Is there an elegant way? Not necessarily a `ggplot2()` solution, but one that works on `seq()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the `length.out` argument of `seq` rather than the `by` argument. That is,

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(y_min, y_max, length.out = 6))
```

You may want to wrap the sequence in `round()` to avoid undue precision.